# Insterstellar Psycho - What damage can he do?

Tags: internal-consistency, space, weapons, science-in-society

The Interstellar Psycho just wants to cause damage to others. He regularly shoots intense laser bursts in all directions into space from his base on Earth's Moon. He sends one every hour.

**Question**

If he always fires to miss any objects within the solar system, what are his chances of hitting anything at all (that is the size of the moon or larger) before the heat-death of the Universe?

The equatorial diameter of the Moon is approximately 3480 km / 2,160 miles

Edit - The psycho starts today and continues firing continuously for ten years.

Comment: At what speed does he launch the cannonballs?  What are the qualities of these cannonballs?  How powerful is "damaging"?  This is an unanswerable question; you need lots more qualifiers, or this is far too broad.

Comment: @jdunlop - I've removed the cannonballs and damaging.

Comment: I don't get the science tag. The question is not about science and the perception of science in a fictional world.

Comment: In the known universe/visible or in the infinite total universe? Also are we talking about a real Laser or some kind of magic infinitely coherent beam of light?

Comment: Long before the heat death of the universe the Earth and Moon will likely be consumed by the Sun's expansion.  Say about 4 billion years.  Even if not swallowed the Sun will be so large in the sky that it would be almost a certainty to hit in relatively few shots.

Comment: @StephenG Question states avoidance of object within the solar system, that would tend to include the sun.

Comment: @Ash I'm dubious that you can avoid hitting the Sun when it's swallows the Earth and Moon (or indeed still be in a condition capable of firing a laser).  The question is without a much better definition for the laser's capabilities (as you pointed out) and the definition of "hit".  There's still no Worldbuilding aspect and I'm not sure there's any point here.

Comment: @StephenG Obviously he's going to have to stop firing a _lot_ earlier than anticipated.

Comment: @StephenG - I've added the proviso that he only shoots for ten years.

Comment: @Ash - The known universe.

Comment: Do you want that anything to be hit by a collimated laser beam, or by scattered photons? The higher your divergence, the greater is the chance of hitting anything - but then the target won't take any damage if hit by scattered photons.

Comment: VTC OT:Unclear.  If you modified the question to read "if he fired his laser once per hour, what is the liklihood of hitting another celestial body outside our solar system in one year? (ignore laser strength, assume can hit at any distance.)" you'd have a theoretically answerable question.  Otherwise, you need to provide considerable information: laser strength, focusing abilities, what your Psycho considers "damage," etc.

Comment: Relevant XKCD what if: https://what-if.xkcd.com/13/

Answer (score 3):

With a real laser almost certainly 100%, but no-one will notice. Regardless of how powerful the burst is it will disperse to a huge, multiple light year wide, cone of weak light by the time it transverses interstellar distances. That cone will hit a lot of things but won't be noticeable when it does.

With some kind of infinitely coherent burst of energy that doesn't disperse in transit his odds of hitting an object in the observable universe are non-zero but I can't find any data that allow me give you a figure.

Comment: Depends on effective aperture of the beam. If entire Moon diameter is the aperture, the beam would stay focused for hundreds of light years.

Comment: :-)  Is this assuming the advent of photons onto any non-solar-system celestial object constitutes "damage?"  I'm just curious.  It's kindof a photonic Prime Directive type of thing (never contaminate another celestial body with photons intentionally emitted by the Psycho, you know, PPP: Psychonic Prime Directive... which he violates constantly!).